# How to specify the initialValue type when using React.context (rewrite)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

```
'use client';

import { useState, createContext, useMemo } from 'react';

type MessageStatus = 'default' | 'success' | 'error';

export type MessageProps = {
  type: MessageStatus;
  payload: string;
};

type ContextType = [
  MessageProps[],
  {
    add(message: MessageProps): void;
  },
];

export const MessageContext = createContext<ContextType | null>(null);

export function MessageProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageProps[]>([]);
  const actions = useMemo(
    () => ({
      add(message: MessageProps) {
        setMessages((prev) => prev.concat([message]));
        setTimeout(
          () => setMessages((prevMessages) => prevMessages.slice(1)),
          5000,
        );
      },
    }),
    [],
  );
  const value = useMemo(() => [messages, actions], [messages, actions]);
  return (
    <MessageContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</MessageContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The above code would result in the following error:

```
Type '(MessageProps[] | { add(message: MessageProps): void; })[]' is not assignable to type '[MessageProps[], { add(message: MessageProps): void; }]'.
  Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
```

However, in the code below, it works fine.
How should I type the `initialValue` of `createContext` to make the above code work without errors?

```
export const MessageContext = createContext<MessageProps[] | null>(null);
export const MessageActionsContext = createContext<{
  add(message: MessageProps): void;
} | null>(null);
export function MessageProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageProps[]>([]);
  const actions = useMemo(
    () => ({
      add(message: MessageProps) {
        setMessages((prev) => prev.concat([message]));
        setTimeout(
          () => setMessages((prevMessages) => prevMessages.slice(1)),
          5000,
        );
      },
    }),
    [],
  );
  return (
    <MessageContext.Provider value={messages}>
      <MessageActionsContext.Provider value={actions}>
        {children}
      </MessageActionsContext.Provider>
    </MessageContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use a tuple type as the initial value for createContext, you need to specify the of the initial value `[] as ContextType.`

```
export const MessageContext = createContext<ContextType | null>(
  [] as ContextType,
);
```